# Finish inserting new line-feature (PyQgis + GUI)?

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt

I'm writing a small graphical plugin where users should be able to add new (multi-)line features to an existing layer.

This is what I've already done:

- I have two buttons, one to trigger the insert, the other to stop the inserting when the user is satisfied with his line-feature.
- The first button works properly. It selects the associated layer, starts editing it and triggers the Add Feature Button:

  ```
  self.iface.setActiveLayer(scenario_layer)
  scenario_layer.startEditing()
  self.iface.actionAddFeature().trigger()
  ```
- Then the user is able to just click in the map to add vertices.

My problem:

I want the user being able to insert the line using a button, instead of a right click. I cannot figure out how to trigger that in PyQgis.
I still can commitChanges() to the layer, but this won't insert the line to the layer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it change something if you add the line `scenario_layer.updateExtents()` below the commitChanges()?

Comment: Nope, already had that one in the code before but seems to do nothing. Above, or below. Thanks